# reading codec info of a file in python

Tags: python

I have a container file, for eg a .mp4. How do I read the audio codec and video codec info of this file using Python. I just need to find out the codec info. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You need to know exactly which file you want to read, then look for a description of how that data is stored. You can not do this for a generic file

Answer (score 4):

You can use [MediaInfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/).

There is a [Python wrapper](https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for it. You can also use [the dll directly](http://mediainfo.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mediainfo/MediaInfoLib/trunk/Source/Example/HowToUse_Dll.py?view=markup)